# Load Excel File To Powerbuilder

Tags: excel, file, text, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have this code for buttonclicked event to load excel and text file to powerbuilder and the excel data is not copied  i.e ll_return_xls <= 0 and thus when i want to load it to db i will get error since it has no value or data in it...The problem here is i get the data from text file but not from the excel file...Any help will be appreciated

```
    long    ll_return
    long    ll_return_xls
   OLEObject  excel 




   IF rb_file.checked then
  IF dwo.Name = "b_browse_meters"   THEN // Browse Button Clicked for Text

ll_return = GetFileOpenName ( "Select Meter File", is_fullname, is_filename, "TXT", &
    "Text Files (*.txt), *.txt" )

if ll_return < 1 then 
    gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX28", "", "", OK!)
    return
end if

  END IF // Browse Button Clicked
  END IF

   IF dwo.Name ="b_browse_meters_xls" THEN // Browse Button Clicked for Excel

ll_return_xls = GetFileOpenName ( "Select Meter File", is_fullname, is_filename, "XLS", &
    "Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls" )

if ll_return_xls < 1 then 
    gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX28", "", "", OK!)
    return
end if

excel = create oleobject
    excel.ConnectToNewObject( "excel.application" )
excel.visible = false
excel.workbooks.open( is_fullname)
excel.Range("A1:A2").Select
excel.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select()
ClipBoard('')
excel.Selection.Copy()
ClipBoard('')
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
excel.Disconnectobject()
Destroy excel

END IF // Browse Button Clicked
```

And Function  to load it the text and excel data

```
long    ll_return, ll_arr_len, ll_loop, ll_indx, ll_pass = 0
integer     li_rc, li_file_nbr, li_fr_rc //File Read Return Code
string      ls_file, ls_line, ls_msg
string lsa_meters[], lsa_meter_pass[]
string ls_meters
long    ll_total_valid, ll_total_aparatos

SetPointer(HourGlass!)
if IsValid(w_progbar) then Close(w_progbar)
openwithparm(w_progbar,"Uploading file data ...")
w_progbar.uo_progress_bar.set_position(10)

li_rc = SUCCESS
ll_total_aparatos = 0
ll_total_valid = 0

// Open file
if li_rc = SUCCESS then
ls_file = is_fullname
li_file_nbr = FileOpen(ls_file, LineMode!)
if IsNull(li_file_nbr) or li_file_nbr < 1 then
    li_rc = NO_ACTION
end if
end if

// Read file, store serial numbers into array lsa_meters[]
if li_rc = SUCCESS then // File Opened
ll_indx = 0
do while ll_indx > -1 and li_rc = SUCCESS
    li_fr_rc = FileRead(li_file_nbr, ls_line)
    choose case li_fr_rc
        case is > 0
            ll_indx ++
        lsa_meters[ll_indx] = ls_line
        case 0, -100
            ll_indx = -1
        case -1
            li_rc = FAILURE
            gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX21", "", "", OK!)
        end choose
loop

if li_rc = SUCCESS then // File Read OK
    ll_arr_len = UpperBound(lsa_meters)

    if ll_arr_len > 0 then // Data found in file
        for ll_loop = 1 to ll_arr_len step 1
            if ib_meter then
                ll_return = wf_luhn_check(lsa_meters[ll_loop])
                ll_total_valid ++
            else
                if Len(lsa_meters[ll_loop]) >= 9 then
                    ll_return = 1
                    ll_total_valid ++
                else
                    ll_return = -1
                end if
            end if
            if ll_return = 1 then
                if wf_aparatos_check(lsa_meters[ll_loop]) <= 0 then
                    ll_return = 1
                else
                    ll_return = -1
                    ll_total_aparatos ++
                end if
            end if
            if ll_return = 1 then
                ll_pass++
                lsa_meter_pass[ll_pass] = lsa_meters[ll_loop]
                ls_meters = ls_meters + lsa_meters[ll_loop] + isk_TAB_PB
            end if
            w_progbar.uo_progress_bar.set_position(50 + ((ll_loop / ll_arr_len) * 40))
        next

        ll_arr_len = UpperBound(lsa_meter_pass)

        if ll_arr_len > 0 then
            dw_datos_ingreso.Object.num_ini[1] = lsa_meter_pass[1]
            dw_datos_ingreso.Object.num_fin[1] = lsa_meter_pass[ll_arr_len]

            is_meters_passed = ls_meters // Concatenated string of meter serial no.
            il_apa_filemeters_count = ll_arr_len // Number of meters
        else
            li_rc = FAILURE
            if ib_meter then
                gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX27", "", "", OK!)
            else
                gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX22", "", "", OK!)
            end if
            if ll_total_valid = ll_total_aparatos then
                gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX23", "", "", OK!)
            end if
        end if
    else
        li_rc = FAILURE
        gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX24", "", "", OK!)
    end if // Data found in file
end if // File Read OK
end if // File Opened

w_progbar.uo_progress_bar.set_position(100)
Close(w_progbar)

//Clean up
if li_file_nbr > 0 then
if FileClose(li_file_nbr) = FAILURE then
    li_rc = FAILURE
    gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX25", "", "", OK!)
end if
 end if

 if ll_total_aparatos > 0 then
gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EW140", String(ll_total_aparatos) , "", OK!)
 end if

 if li_rc = FAILURE then
gnv_msg.f_mensaje("EX26", "", "", OK!)
RETURN FALSE
  end if

  RETURN TRUE
```

Comment: So is the excel file not opened or loaded? or you just cannot read the values once it is opened?

Comment: when the excel file is taken to the function for loading it gives this as the output ÐÏà¡±á ÿ  instead of a string of data e.g as677878 as value for 1 row

Comment: I'm still not clear on what problem you're asking help for. The only place in the script you've provided for the return value you mentioned is a failure in GetFileOpenName(). It will probably help people if you narrowed down the problem more and came with a more specific question. However, after your Excel copy command, the next line wipes out the clipboard, apparently wiping out the only data you're getting from Excel. Not clear if this is the problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ODBC driver directly to the Excel file, and then build a Pipeline object that moves the data from the spreadsheet directly into the database.   Don't write code you don't need to.

Comment: The code i pasted for function works well for a text file in the event button clicked   and here is the code for the text event

Comment: NoazDad   See my Improved Question Above